# NSUndoManager calls method that no longer exists

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsundomanager

I have a complex situation where I have a view controller and several sub view controllers.

**Situation A:** When I change the sub view controller, I record the change in NSUndoManager, and the undo calls the undo method in the sub view controller and works fine.

```
-(void)setElementTransform:(NSString *)transform
{
    NSUndoManager *undoManager = [Global sharedGlobalInstance].undoMgr;
    [undoManager registerUndoWithTarget:self selector:@selector(setElementTransform:) object:self.element.transform];
    self.element.transform = transform;
    self.view.transform = CGAffineTransformFromString(transform);
}
```

**Situation B:** This is a bit more complex - when I remove the sub view controller, I record the undo method (in the main view controller) in NSUndoManager. When I undo that remove, the NSUndoManager calls the undo method in the main view controller, which recreates the sub view controller. That works fine too.

The problem is that if I do Situation A followed by Situation B, I have two in the undo stack. I can undo Situation B, but Situation A has reference to an undo method in a sub view controller that no longer exists (it was removed and recreated by deleting and undoing in Situation B).

I don't think there is any way of updating NSUndoManager so that I can change the reference to the old sub view controller?

How else could I cope with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could register all undo actions with an object that will not be discarded.  For example on the top level view controller, or even the app delegate, or a separate singleton.  Then you would need to include in the object argument of registerUndoWithTarget:selector:object: enough information to apply the undo action on the appropriate sub view controller *or its replacement*.

If you just need to get actions targeted at the dead sub view controller out of the undo stack, call removeAllActionsWithTarget:self in the dealloc (or viewWillDisappear, or viewDidUnload, as appropriate) method of the sub view controller.

Comment: Thank you - removeAllActionsWithTarget:self is the key to stop the crashing, but it effectively removes that object from the undo tree. I will implement your other suggestion in a custom undo manager at a future point.